# How to pass non const dynamic multidimensional array to function wanting const multidimensional array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic, parameter-passing, constants

I've written the following function in **C** to print out a dynamically created matrix but guarantee that inside the function I

1. Can't modify the pointer I'm given
2. Can't modify any of the interior pointers
3. Can't modify any of the numbers in the matrix

---

```
 void const2dPrinter(const int *const *const mat, const int numRows, const int numCols){
  for(int i =0; i < numRows; ++i){
    for(int j =0; j < numCols; ++j){
      printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
 }
```

I attempt to call the function in main as follows

```
int main(){
  int numRows = 3;
  int numCols = 4;
  int** mat = (int**) malloc(numRows * sizeof(int*);
  for(int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i){
    mat[i] = (int*)malloc(numCols * sizeof(int));
    for(int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j){
      mat[i][j] = (i +1) * (j+1);
    }
  }
  const2dPrinter(mat, numRows, numCols);
...
}
```

But I get the following error from the compiler

```
error: passing argument 1 of 'const2dPrinter' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   const2dPrinter(mat, numRows, numCols);
note: expected 'const int * const* const' but argument is of type 'int **'
   void const2dPrinter(const int *const *const const mat, const int numRows, const int numCols)
```

My IDE gives the following error:

```
Parameter type mismatch: Assigning int** to const int* const* const* discards const qualifier.
```

The code will work if I remove the first const in the declararation of the function. Going from
   void const2dPrinter(**const** int *const *const mat, ...){

to
   void const2dPrinter(int *const *const mat, ...){

but then I'm able to modify the values of the matrix in const2dPrinter, which I don't want to be able to do.

I know that I can cast the `int**` to a `const int *const *const` when calling the function to get things to work as shown below, but I'm incredibly confused as to why what I have right now doesn't work as everything I have read says that you should be able to have a const pointer point at at a non const value.

```
const2dPrinter((const int* const* const) mat, numRows, numCols); //this works
```

I've tried searching for a solution but haven't been able to find one. The code will compile on a C++ compiler without issue but won't work on my C compiler (gcc).

Any advice on how to fix my problem as well as an explanation of why what I have now doesn't work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the ugly cast (although the last `const` is redundant). It is an oversight in the C specification that there is no implicit conversion to change `T **` to `T const * const *`.

I think in practice people tend to end up just not using `const` in situations where there will be pointers-to-pointers, or pointers-to-arrays, because of this problem.  You can work around it with casts, and/or a generic selector etc. but things quickly seem to get complicated to support what should be a simple operation.

---

For your specific situation another approach might be to use a single-dimension array to store the matrix. (This is probably going to be more efficient at runtime due to requiring a smaller number of allocations).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Bummed to hear that cast is a necessity :(

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass the parameter as a *constant pointer* to *constant int* you want your parameter to be:

```
void const2dprinter (const int* const* mat, const int numrows, const int numcols)
```

There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Your allocations should also use the dereferenced pointer to insure you always obtain the proper type-size, e.g.

```
    int **mat = malloc (numrows * sizeof *mat);
    ...
        mat[i] = malloc (numcols * sizeof *mat[i]);
```

Build good habits now. If you allocate memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. Keep track of what you allocate, and then `free` the memory before losing the pointer. A simple free function is all that is required, e.g.

```
void mat_free (int **mat, const int numrows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numrows; i++)
        free (mat[i]);      /* free rows */
    free (mat);             /* free pointers */
}
```

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void const2dprinter (const int* const* mat, const int numrows, const int numcols)
{
    for (int i =0; i < numrows; ++i){
        for(int j =0; j < numcols; ++j)
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void mat_free (int **mat, const int numrows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numrows; i++)
        free (mat[i]);      /* free rows */
    free (mat);             /* free pointers */
}

int main (void) {

    int numrows = 3;
    int numcols = 4;
    int **mat = malloc (numrows * sizeof *mat);

    for (int i = 0; i < numrows; ++i) {
        mat[i] = malloc (numcols * sizeof *mat[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < numcols; ++j)
            mat[i][j] = (i +1) * (j+1);
    }
    const2dprinter ((int const * const *)mat, numrows, numcols);
    mat_free (mat, numrows);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$. /bin/mat_const_int_2d
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using sizeof on the derefenced pointer to ensure that I always allocate the correct amount of space. In your answer it looks like you used a cast in the call and based on @M.M.'s answer it seems like it is a necessity. The cast was what I was hoping to avoid but it doesn't sound like there is a way around it :(

Comment: No, there is no way around the cast to compile without a warning (which all your code should compile cleanly without warning). Without the cast, you receive the warning `"expected ‘const int * const*’ but argument is of type ‘int **’"`. (it is a warning -- the code will work, but do not accept code until it compiles *without* warnings) On gcc/clang always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (minimum) or for VS (`cl.exe`) use `/W3` (minimum) or you can use `/W4` -- but you will generate a number of non-code related warning.